# French Naturalization through marriage if living abroad

Tags: france, citizenship, residency

I'm an Indian citizen and my spouse in France. We are planning to move out of France next year. Can I still apply for French citizenship after 4 years of marriage? Or is 3 year residence in France necessary?

I haven't found a clear answer on the internet elsewhere! A lot of places say that residency doesn't matter as long as I have B1 level in French and we've been living together the entire time.

Answer (score 1):

If you have been living in France without interruption since your marriage for more than 3 years, and you have been married for at least 4 years with your French husband, you can apply to naturalize.

If you have been living in France for less than 3 years after your marriage, then the following conditions apply:

1. If your French spouse was entered in the consular registers during your stay abroad: You must have been married for at least 4 years on the date of your naturalization application.
2. If your French spouse has not been entered in the consular registers: you must have been married for at least 5 years on the date of your naturalization application.

References:

- [Service-public.fr](https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F2726)
- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_nationality_law#Eligibility_resulting_from_marriage_to_a_French_citizen)

Comment: That's great information! Just to confirm I'm rrading this correctly, we can move abroad next year, my husband registers with the consulate and as soon as we complete 4yrs of marriage, I can apply to the local embassy for Naturalization?

Comment: @Nina Well, yes, the wording seems to have no other meaning. You can apply after 4 years of your marriage if your husband is registered, regardless of your time spent in France.